# get permission from foursquare

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, foursquare

I want to send email of a user to foursquare and get permission about the user data. But the user should allow me to get information about him/her. How can I make user to authorize my application in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get user information (and for a user to authorise you to access their information) is to use the OAuth workflow as detailed [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth). There is no way to do this authentication via email.